# RecyclerView inside another RecyclerView affects scroll position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using RecyclerView inside another RecyclerView and when loading data the RecyclerView scroll to position 1 not position 0.

How can I make the parent RecyclerView scroll to position 0?

Comment: recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);

Answer (score 0):

Try it!

```
recyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
        }
    },100);
```

Comment: recyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                recyclerView.scrollTo(0,0);
            }
        },100);

Comment: change scrollToPosition to scrollTo

Answer (score 0):

This line solve my issue
recyclerView.setFocusable(false);